# How to get the data from SAP to ASP.net using SAP GateWay Service

Tags: asp.net, service, sap-gateway

Please help how to get the data from SAP gate way services. SAP team given this url::-
http://Gateway_host:Gateway_port/sap/opu/odata/sap/ API SRV/ApplicationPendingListSet?$filter=UserID eq 'XXXXX' and user id & password. how to get this data in asp.net.

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string SAP_ODATA_URL = @"http://ApplicationURL";
string SAP_ODATA_QUERY = "MethodName?$filter=Parameter eq '" + extensionAttribute13 + "'";
string requestUrl = SAP_ODATA_URL + SAP_ODATA_QUERY;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXX", "XXX");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(responseFromServer));
    xmlReader.Read();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(xmlReader, XmlReadMode.Auto);
}
```